# How to debug errors in saving images in database from different inputs

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save images in mysql using PHP 
but I keep getting an error saying `Fatal error: Call to undefined function saveimage() in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHPv2.0\Clients\subreqv2.php on line 100`

And this is my code:

```
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <br/>
    <!-- img1 file browser -->
        <div>
        <input type="file" name="image1"/>
        <br/>
        </div>              

    <!-- img2 file browser -->
        <div>
        <input type="file" name="image2"/>
        <br/>
        </div>              

    <!-- img3 file browser -->
        <div>
        <input type="file" name="image3"/>
        <br/>
        </div>              


    <!-- img4 file browser -->
        <div>
        <input type="file" name="image4"/>
        <br/>
        </div>              


    <!-- img5 file browser -->
        <div>
        <input type="file" name="image5"/>
        <br/>
        </div>              


    <!-- img6 file browser -->
        <div>
        <input type="file" name="image6"/>
        <br/>
        </div>              


    <!-- img7 file browser -->
        <div>
        <input type="file" name="image7"/>
        <br/>

        </div>              
        <input type="submit" name="sumit" value="Upload">
        </form>

        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['sumit']))
        {
            if(getimagesize($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'])== FALSE)
            {
                echo "Please select an image.";
            }
            else
            {
                $image1=addslashes($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
                $name1=addslashes($_FILES['image1']['name']);
                $image1=file_get_contents($image1);
                $image1=base64_encode($image1);

                $image2=addslashes($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name']);
                $name2=addslashes($_FILES['image2']['name']);
                $image2=file_get_contents($image2);
                $image2=base64_encode($image2);

                $image3=addslashes($_FILES['image3']['tmp_name']);
                $name3=addslashes($_FILES['image3']['name']);
                $image3=file_get_contents($image3);
                $image3=base64_encode($image3);

                $image4=addslashes($_FILES['image4']['tmp_name']);
                $name4=addslashes($_FILES['image4']['name']);
                $image4=file_get_contents($image4);
                $image4=base64_encode($image4);

                $image5=addslashes($_FILES['image5']['tmp_name']);
                $name5=addslashes($_FILES['image5']['name']);
                $image5=file_get_contents($image5);
                $image5=base64_encode($image5);

                $image6=addslashes($_FILES['image6']['tmp_name']);
                $name6=addslashes($_FILES['image6']['name']);
                $image6=file_get_contents($image6);
                $image6=base64_encode($image6);

                $image7=addslashes($_FILES['image7']['tmp_name']);
                $name7=addslashes($_FILES['image7']['name']);
                $image7=file_get_contents($image7);
                $image7=base64_encode($image7);
                saveimage();

            }

        }
        //displayimage();
        function saveimagesaveimage($name1,$image1,$name2,$image2,$name3,$image3,$name4,$image4,$name5,$image5,$name6,$image6,$name7,$image7)
        {
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("dummy",$con);
            $qry="INSERT INTO images (name1,image1,name2,image2,name3,image3,name4,image4,name5,image5,name6,image6,name7,image7) VALUES ('$name1','$image1','$name2','$image2','$name3','$image3','$name4','$image4','$name5','$image5','$name6','$image6','$name7','$image7')";
            $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
            if($result)
            {
                echo "<br/>Image successfully uploaded.";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<br/>Error in uploading image.";  
            }


        }

    /*  function displayimage()
        {
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("dummy",$con);
            $qry="SELECT * FROM images";
            $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo '<img height="100" width="100" src="data:image;base64,'.$row['image'].'">';
            }
        }

    */



        ?>
    </body>
```

Can anyone point out to me where did I go wrong?

**Note:** nevermind the use of `mysql` instead of `msqli` or `PDO` I just have to make this work so I could base my main project here.

Thanks for the help in advance. I'll appreciate it.

Comment: it is `saveimagesaveimage`

Comment: Man thanks ! @FastSnail your comment should be placed in the answers thanks for the help +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end you are calling `saveimage()` function, while in the code you have written the function name `saveimagesaveimage()`.

Not only that you are passing many parameters to the function where it is initialised but where you are calling the `saveimage()` function even with the wrong name, no parameters are passed to it.

Comment: Oh my bad, it should be typo, thanks man for figuring it out.

Comment: @user Glad to help :)

Comment: I called the function like this `saveimage($name1,$image1,$name2,$image2,$name3,$image3,$name4,$image4,$name5,$image5,$name6,$image6,$name7,$image7);` and it worked. +1 for helping me